# Excel Macro text-to-column whole column

Tags: vba, excel

I got some values from a log file and want to separate them whenever a ";" appear!

This is the code I got

```
 Sub ClearTextToColumns()
    On Error Resume Next
    If IsEmpty(Range("A1")) Then Range("A1") = "XYZZY"

    Range("A1").Select
    Dim Time As Range
    Set Time = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0))
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

       Range("A1").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, _
        Space:=False, _
        Other:=True, _
        OtherChar:=";"
    If Range("A1") = "XYZZY" Then Range("A1") = ""
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Description

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Set newRange = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0))
    MsgBox newRange.Address
    Loop

End Sub
```

It's only the A1 row that get fixed.... tried to exchange "A1" with the Time range but didn't do any wonders...

Comment: `Range("A1").TextToColumns` This must contain the full column range you wish to apply the 'text to columns' formatting to.

Answer (score 0):

I added a comment, but also going to add an answer which will solve the issue of only A1 converting across the columns.

You just need to ensure the entire range which you want to convert is included within the `.TextToColumns` method.

You can provide it with a variable range by using the below code:

```
Sub split_text()
    Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lrow, 1)).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), _
            DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
            Semicolon:=True, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```